# Does a Simulacrum get the Hand and Eye of Vecna too?

Tags: dnd-5e, artifacts, simulacrum

So someone is attuned to the [*Hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/11114-hand-of-vecna) and [*Eye of Vecna*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/11112-eye-of-vecna). It is an appendage at this point. That person then casts [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) targeting themselves. Does the clone gain the Hand and the Eye as well since it's attached to the original?

Comment: With that behind us, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 20):

### No.

Although grafted onto the recipient, the Hand and Eye are still magic items, and therefore "equipment".

The [Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell says (emphasis added):

> [The simulacrum] appears to be the same as the original, but it has half the creature's hit point maximum and is formed **without any equipment**.

Comment: Makes sense, but it also makes me wonder whether the simulacrated version would be missing a hand and an eye or not.

Comment: @Dopplegamer I think it would lack them — they were removed to attach the artifacts, after all, and simulacrum says nothing about replacing missing limbs